# Installing Vista x64 Ultimate on EVGA board with Nvidia chipset

Tags: windows-vista, bsod

I am trying to install Windows Vista x64 Ultimate on EVGA board (123-YW-E175-A1) with a Nvidia chipset and a Q6700 CPU.

The install disk boots, loads some files, then I get a BSOD.

Any advice?

Comment: You need post the information from the BSOD. Not all BSODs are equal.

Comment: Does the motherboard have any form of RAID?

Comment: Is the BIOS set to x64?

Comment: Is this a custom or off-the-shelf machine? If off the shelf, what is the make and model. If it is custom, please list the mainboard, discs, and ram makes and models

Comment: @Daniel For loading a x64 OS the motherboard and CPU just needs to support x64. For 64Bit Virtualisation you need to set the x64 Intel flags on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using media with service pack 1 or better. Ideally sp2...

Comment: +1 Nice one Jeff. Didn't think of that. The instructions for slipstreaming SP1 also works for 2 and can be found here: http://www.pronetworks.org/forums/slipstream-sp1-to-windows-vista-t103246.html

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest trying to boot with the x86 CD and see if that works. Also providing the motherboard model number might help a lot.

It could be that you have a faulty Motherboard, or the motherboard needs a firmware update. The processor could also have an affect.

*This is focussed at hardware causes of the problem*

Answer (score 0):

I encountered "`STOP 0x0000007B INACCESSABLE_BOOT_DEVICE`" installing Vista for the first time on a Dell notebook. The reasons came down to:

- The Vista install media did not include the [Intel Matrix Storage](http://www.intel.com/design/chipsets/matrixstorage_sb.htm) driver
- My BIOS was in [Advanced Host Controller Interface (AHCI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface) mode by default (it shipped with a lower grade version of Vista) which the oringinal media couldn't handle without the above driver.

If you toggle your hard drives into IDE mode in the BIOS you can get through the install, update drivers and media and then follow instructions in this [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976) to toggle back to AHCI mode.

Alternatively, you can load the Matrix driver onto a USB key and supply it when the Windows install requests new drivers (watch for a "press spacebar prompt during the pre-install/blue screen with white text phase).

Hope this helps.